# managing existing hosts with vagrant bypassing the provider

Tags: vagrant

I'm managing a few web services residing on different fixed hosts with ssh. I wanted to use vagrant so that I can edit local files and have them synced automagically.
however I'm having problems as I'm not using no provider or box, it's a fixed host and it feels like I'm going against vagramt's aim.

here's my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
  VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.ssh.host = ...
  config.ssh.username = ...
  config.ssh.private_key_path = ".ssh/id_rsa"
  config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "..."
  config.vm.box = "myhost"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

and here's my bootstrap.sh file:

```
pip install flask sqlalchemy
```

but I can't make vagrant skip providing (with virtualbox or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as it always comes out - fighting against your tool in order to force it to do things it's not designed to are a bad idea.

there was probably a way to make vagrant use a void box but vagrant is too much for just keeping 2 directories synced. I found this nice [tool](https://github.com/drunomics/syncd) that does exactly the same as vagrant for sync just without all the provider/provision etc.